# SOCKS proxy over Reverse SSH

Tags: ssh, socks

I've seen a similar question but it's different enough for the answer not to quite work.

I have two Debian Buster hosts - one in a private network (A); one in Azure (B).

I'd like Host A to initiate a reverse SSH connection from Host B. Then Host B subsequently to open a SOCKS proxy listener so that connections to that are tunnelled back to Host A. I would like to achieve all of this just by entering commands on Host A.

I know that I can set up the reverse SSH tunnel from Host B to Host A (initiated by Host A) like so:

```
ssh -R b:localhost:a b.b.b.b
```

`a` = the listening port on Host A
`b` = the listening port on Host B
and `b.b.b.b` is the IP address of Host B.

How can I then get the second part - automatically creating a SOCKS proxy listener on Host B - to work? Is it even possible? Or would I need to create a script on Host B that creates the SOCKS proxy listener whenever `netstat` shows the reverse SSH tunnel is Established (or similar)?

Editted to try and clarify based on first answer.

Comment: A simple `ssh -R b user@b.b.b.b` makes Host B listen on port `b` and tunnel to Host A, which acts as a SOCKS proxy, the requests it receives there. Is this what you are looking for? (Especially if it's not,) showing a bigger picture (e.g. a browser → Host B, port b → (via tunnel) Host A → some server on A's private network) may help.

Comment: It might be what I'm looking for actually..! Easy to overthink this. I've just tried it and Host B is only listening on the loopback though.

Comment: Likely because of `GatewayPorts` in `sshd`'s configuration on Host B (see `man sshd_config`). If it solves your issue, please feel free to self-answer your question (I'm not posting an answer right now).

Comment: Yes, gatewayports was the reason. Thanks fra-san - much appreciated! SSH to b.b.b.b:b doesn't work but I'll do a bit of troubleshooting and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Have you established the first step, reverse ssh connection? If yes, then your local host A should be listening to an arbitary port, for example 2222, through which traffic will be forwarded to port 22 on Azure server B (if default sshd port is used on B).

- Second step, socks proxy.

On host A type,
`ssh -p 2222 -D 4444 -N localhost`
I'm arbitary choosing port 4444 on local (host A) for the SOCKS proxy to listen.

Traffic:
4444 local A -> 2222 local A -> 22 Azure B

To test, use socks proxy setting on a browser, for example Chrome,
`google-chrome --proxy-server="socks://localhost:4444"`
or choose SOCKS version, 4 or 5
`google-chrome --proxy-server="socks4://localhost:4444"`

If everything is good, you should browse the Internet using you azure machine as gateway/proxy. Check your public IP to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unless I've misunderstood, this will open the listener on Host A to forward to Host B though. I'm after the other way around. i.e. Host B opens a SOCKS listener and forwards traffic to Host A. But Host A sets everything up (no commands entered on Host B).